# ARM A76 watchpoint does not work, after correctly configuring the register

Tags: debugging, arm64, watchpoint, threadx

I want to monitor a specified address on an ARM A76 machine and enter an exception when the address is loaded from. However, I did the configuration and did not get the exception.

My process is as follows:

1. Set `MDSCR_EL1.KDE` and `MDSCR_EL1.MDE` to `1` to enable debug exception in EL1.
2. Configure the `OSLAR_EL1` register to unlocked.
3. Configure `DBGWVR0_EL1` and `DBGWCR0_EL1`, and make sure store instruction (LSC == 0b10) to the address in `DBGWVR0_EL1` will trap.

I use mrs Instruction to read the relevant register, but can not find the reason. My machine as follows:

1. ARM A76+Threadx Rtos
2. The exception to running the program is EL1.
   Register print as follows:
   `DAIF`: `0x0`
   `OSLSR_EL1`: `0x8`
   `CurrentEL`: `0x4`
   `MDSCR_EL1`: `0xa000`
   `DBGWVR0_EL1`: `0xd021b600`
   `DBGWCR0_EL1`: `0xf9`

I configured `MDSCR_EL1.SS` to `1`, and the CPU entered an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You set `DBGWCR0_EL1.PAC` to `0b00`, which selects neither EL1 nor EL0. Set it to `0b01` for EL1, `0b10` for EL0, or `0b11` for both (see "Table D2-13 Summary of watchpoint HMC, SSC, and PAC encodings" in [the manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest) for a complete overview).

So if you want your watchpoint to only hit at EL1, set `DBGWCR0_EL1` to `0xfb`.